Back button using referrer in flask
@app.route('/show-empty')
def show_empty():
    res = Empty.query.all()
    return render_template('empty.html', results=res)



@app.route('/remove-empty/<int:emp_id>')
def remove(emp_id):
    Empty.query.filter(Empty.id == emp_id).delete()
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Updated Item!')
    return redirect(url_for('show_empty'))

html:
    <div>
       <button> <a href="{{request.referrer}}"> Back </a> </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <table class="results-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>iaf</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th class="button-column"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% if results %}
                {% for res in results %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ res.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ res.loc }}</td>
                        <td>{{ res.iaf }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="/remove-empty/{{ res.id }}">
                                <button>Remove</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>


I'm using this to manage a display of empty items, and for each item, a button to remove it from the list. On the page, I have a back button that uses a request.referrer inside the HTML template, but if I press the button to remove something, I assume it updates the referrer, and then I can't go back to the same page I entered the display from. Any ideas on how to manage this?
